# iOS: OverlayView. Which is the right view to put it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, overlay

I have an application which saves some values on a bluetooth device. This of course takes some time.
When I exit a settings screen, the new settings get saved to this device. During the save process I'm putting an overlay view containing an activity indicator over the screen to block any inputs. When the save process is finished, the view gets a callback to remove the pop to the previous view and remove the overlay view. I tried to implement this idea in different ways, but always having an unwelcome side effect.

**First implementation:**
I put the overlayview over the keyWindow of the application. 
Everything is block as wished. But when receiving the callback the overlay view gets removed first and with a little delay the transition back to the previous view gets executed, even the [overlay removeFromSuperView] is in the "viewDidDisappear" method.

```
-(void)putOverlayView{
    overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
    activity.center =overlayView.center;
    activity.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
    [activity startAnimating];
    [overlayView addSubview:activity];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:overlayView];

}
-(void)savingDone{

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[overlayView removeFromSuperview];


}
```

**Second implementation:**
I put the overlay view on the navigationControllers's view.
The screen gets blocked as wished, even this weird delayed transition effect, which i had in the first implementation idea is gone. But when I'm back at the previous view, the whole input is blocked. Even the overlayview is gone.

```
-(void)putOverlayView{
    overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
    activity.center =overlayView.center;
    activity.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
    [activity startAnimating];
    [overlayView addSubview:activity];
    [self.navigationController view] addSubview:overlayView];

}
-(void)savingDone{

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[overlayView removeFromSuperview];


}
```

**Finally the third implementation:**
I put the overlayview on the [self view].
With this option, I don't have any of the above mentioned effect. Although the NavigationController Title with the back button isn't block, as it is above the [self view]

```
-(void)putOverlayView{
    overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
    activity.center =overlayView.center;
    activity.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
    [activity startAnimating];
    [overlayView addSubview:activity];
    [self view] addSubview:overlayView];

}
-(void)savingDone{

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
[overlayView removeFromSuperview];


}
```

I tried three different ideas, all not working as wished, but always in a different way.
On wich view do I have to put my overlay view to not have any of those unwished effects?
I kind of have the feeling that it would be the right way to put it on the navigationController's view, but how do I have to handle it, that the screen is unlocked for input afterwards?

I hope I gave enough informations, otherwise I will add them to the post of course.

Thanks for any help.